# Is it average loss for tf.estimator.DNNRegressor in tensorflow the same with MSE?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In `model.evaluate of tensorflow`, there is a variable called "**average_loss**". Is it the same as MSE between labels and predictions? However in `tf.losses`, there is another function `mean_squared_error` as well. Which one is the correct MSE?

Answer (score 0):

The loss is computed depending on the model ([see here](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/glossary/#loss)).

Very likely your model uses mean squared error for the loss function, thus the **mean_squared_error** is also the **loss** variable.

Instead, the **average_loss** would be the loss averaged over the last N iterations, because sometimes the training is performed with small batch size and the loss might be noisy.